# Ratio of sum of Normal to sum of cubes of Normal

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, asymptotics

Please help me to find the limiting distribution (as $n \rightarrow \infty$) of the following:
$$ U_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{X_1^3 + X_2^3 + \ldots X_n^3},$$ where $X_i$ are iid $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Have you tried looking at transformations of random variables? For instance, one might try characteristic functions, Laplace-Stieltjes transforms, etcetera.

Comment: Hint: The numerator and denominator are asymptotically bivariate normal.  You may compute their moments directly: their means are obviously zero, the variance of the numerator is $n$, the variance of the denominator is $15n$, and the covariance is $3n$.  (Thus the correlation is $3/\sqrt{15} \approx 0.775$.) To find the limiting distribution, express any zero-mean bivariate normal $(U,V)$ in the form $(A, \beta A + B)$ for independent zero-mean normals $A$ and $B$ and constant $\beta$, then note that the ratio $V/U = \beta + B/A$ is a shifted scaled Cauchy distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If the formulation was $$ U_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n}{Y_1^3 + Y_2^3 + \ldots Y_n^3}$$ where $X_i\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_i \sim N(0,1)$ are independent, it would be just a classic textbook exercise. You use the fact that $$F_n \stackrel{d}{\to} F,\quad G_n \stackrel{d}{\to}G \Rightarrow \frac{F_n}{G_n} \stackrel{d}{\to} \frac{F}{G}$$
and we can conclude that $U$ asymptotes to scaled Cauchy distribution.

But in your formulation, we can't apply the theorem due to dependence. My Monte-Carlo suggests that the limit distribution of $U_n$ is non-degenerate and it has no first moment and is not symmetric. I'd be interested in whether there is a explicit solution to this problem. I feel like the solution can only be written in terms of Wiener process.

[EDIT] Following whuber's hint, note that

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum{X_i},\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum{X_i^3})\stackrel{d}{\to}(Z_1,Z_2)$$ where $$(Z_1,Z_2) \sim N(0,\pmatrix{1 &3 \\3 &15})$$ by noting that $E[X_1^4]=3$ and $E[X_1^6]=15$. (moments of standard normal, $(n-1)!!$ for even $n$) Then by continuous mapping theorem, we have $$U_n \stackrel{d}{\to} \frac{Z_1}{Z_2}$$ Noting that we can write $Z_1 = \frac{1}{5}Z_2+\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}Z_3$ where $Z_3\sim N(0,1)$ and independent of $Z_2$, we conclude that $$U_n \stackrel{d}{\to} \frac{1}{5}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\frac{Z_3}{Z_2} \equiv \frac{1}{5}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{75}}\Gamma$$ where $\Gamma \sim Cauchy$

Answer (score 0):

Some comments, not a full solution.  This is to long for a comment, but really only a comment.  Some properties of the solution. Since the $X_i$ are iid standard normal, which is a symmetric (about zero) distribution, $X_i^3$ will also have symmetric distributions, and sums of (independent) symmetric rv's will be symmetric.  So this is a ratio with the numerator and denominator both symmetric, so will be symmetric. The denominator will have a continuous density which is positive at zero, so we will expect the ratio to lack expectation (It is a general result that if $Z$ is a random variable with continuous density positive at zero, then the $1/X$ will lack expectation.  See [I've heard that ratios or inverses of random variables often are problematic, in not having expectations. Why is that?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722/ive-heard-that-ratios-or-inverses-of-random-variables-often-are-problematic-in)). But here, there is dependence between numerator and denominator which complicates the matter ... (Clearly needs more thought here).

The interesting paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176991795   shows that $x_i^3$ above, the cube of standard normal variables, has an *indeterminate* distribution "in the hamburger sense", that is, it is not determined by its moments!  So the comment above about using transforms, might indicate a difficult way to proceed!