# If $x$ is a normally distributed random variable, then what is the distribution of $x^4$ ? Does it follow a well-known distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

I am interested in the PDF of $x^4$ if $x$ is a normal distributed variable with non-zero mean.

The question is related to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/412249/269684) that considers the cubic of a normal distributed variable. However there only an answer could be given for the zero-mean case.

Comment: The post you reference begins, "The general case of the cube of an normal random variable with any mean is quite complicated,..."  That's correct--and the case of higher powers is even worse.  Use numerical methods.

Comment: There is no "complicated" answer: the best one can do is express it as an integral, but that's perfectly straightforward.  For instance, the characteristic function $\exp(itx^4)$ is an integral. So is the distribution function; it is given by $$\Pr(x\le t)=\Phi(\mu/\sigma+t^{1/4}/\sigma)-\Phi(\mu/\sigma -t^{1/4}/\sigma).$$ Differentiating w.r.t. $t$ yields the density function. But these are trivial applications of definitions: the problem is that there's no further simplification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although *whuber* means there is no simple expression for the probability density distribution of $x^4$ with $x\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$
we can use the CDF from *whuber's* comments to give a simple expression for the PDF:

For the CDF we get
$${\rm Pr}\left(x \le t\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\frac{t^{1/4}}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{t^{1/4}}{\sigma}\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+{\rm erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\frac{t^{1/4}}{\sigma}\right)\right)\right]-\frac{1}{2}\left[1+{\rm erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{t^{1/4}}{\sigma}\right)\right)\right]\tag{1}$$
and for the PDF
$${\rm Pr}\left(t\right){\rm d}t=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}{\rm Pr}\left(x \le t\right){\rm d}t=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma  t^{3/4}}\left({\rm exp}\left(-\frac{\left(t^{1/4}-\mu\right)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)+{\rm exp}\left(-\frac{\left(t^{1/4}+\mu\right)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)\right){\rm d}t \tag{2}$$

The expected value is

$$\mu ^4+6 \mu ^2 \sigma ^2+3 \sigma ^4\tag{3}$$

and variance is
$$8 \left(2 \mu ^6 \sigma ^2+21 \mu ^4 \sigma ^4+48 \mu ^2 \sigma ^6+12 \sigma ^8\right)\tag{4}$$
**Check by simulation**

The histogram for 300 million samples with $\mu=4.5,\sigma=0.4$ agrees well with the theoretical PDF (black). The simulated (theoretical) values for the expectation are $429.591 (429.579)$ and for the variance $151.8317^2 (151.8326^2)$.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Let $Y=X^4$ where $X \sim N(u,\sigma^2)$ so:

$G_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)$

$G_{Y}(y)=P(X^4\leq y)
\\
\\
G_{Y}(y)=P(\sqrt X^4\leq \sqrt{y})
\\
\\
G_{Y}(y)=P(|X^2|\leq \sqrt{y})
\\
\\
G_{Y}(y)=P(X^2\leq \sqrt{y})
\\
\\
G_{Y}(y)=P(|X|\leq y^{1/4})
\\
\\
G_{Y}(y)=P(- y^{1/4}\leq X\leq y^{1/4})
\\
\\
G_{Y}(y)=G_{X}(y^{1/4})-G_{X}(-y^{1/4})
$

Where $G_{X}$ is the cumulative of $X$, remember that $Y$ distribution can be get as $f_{Y}(y)=G_{Y}^{'}(y)$ then:

$f_{Y}(y)=4y^{-3/4}f_{X}(y^{1/4})+4y^{-3/4}f_{X}(-y^{1/4})$

where $f_X(.)$ is the $X$ distribution applied to $(.)$

Now we are seeking for its support:

As $x^4$ is a non negative function so its minimal is equal to $0$ and its maximum is $\infty$ so $Y$ support is given by:

$A_Y=(0,\infty)$

Comment: cristalline clear !